# How to refresh part of the page with AJAX or JSF?

Tags: ajax, jsf

How to render part by part xhtml-page with Primefaces and Ajax (or without). Everything else is working, when the user press the checkbox, message is shown, but usernamecontent is never updated. How to refresh panelgrid in that case? I am totally newbie with AJAX, started today :)

```
<h:outputLabel value="Do you want to create username?" for="description" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testController.selectedNew.asUser}">  
    <p:ajax update="msg" listener="#{testController.selectedNew.addMessage()}"/>
    <p:ajax update="usernamecontent"/> ------> **This is not working!**
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>  

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="usernamecontent" rendered="#{testController.selected.asUser}">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateUserLabel_userUsername}" for="username" />
    <p:inputText id="username" value="#{testController.selectedNew.userUsername.username}" title="#{bundle.CreateUsersTitle_username}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateUserRequiredMessage_username}"/>

    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateUsersLabel_password}" for="password" />
    <p:inputText id="password" value="#{testController.selectedNew.userUsername.password}" title="#{bundle.CreateUserTitle_password}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateUserRequiredMessage_password}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Thanks
Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `usernamecontent` component is by itself conditionally rendered in the server side. In order to be able to ajax-update components, you need to ensure that the component in question is always rendered, because it's in the end the JavaScript which needs to update it in the client side.

You need to wrap it in another component which is always rendered, so that JavaScript can always access it in order to update the content.

```
<h:panelGroup id="usernamecontent">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{testController.selected.asUser}">
        ...
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: That was it :) Thanks a lot, kiitos kiitos! BTW, have you good links to tutorials or ideas of books what to read to get jump start to jsf + ajax? Have you an idea to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003274/jpa-manytomany-in-case-of-users-and-groups/10003452#10003452

Comment: You're welcome. You may find [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) helpful.